# I want to send data to seven segment display without micro-controller

Tags: usb, serial, embedded

I'm new to embedded systems
I want to send data to seven segment display from my pc
could i connect the seven segment display to my pc via serial or usb port or i have to use a micro-controller between them.
the seven segment display i would use like https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on eBay for a TTL Serial USB board. There's millions and they cost a couple of $.

Narrowing it to just ones that can be used to program an Arduino (have a DTR signal) like FT232 based ones would allow you to reprogram the display too if you so wished.

Comment: this means i connect TTL serial usb board in between seven segment display and my pc then i can send data from by pc

Comment: Yep.  The TTL Serial board connects to the USB and provides a new COM port on the computer. You then connect its output to the sparkfun display and send the required commands to it.  For example this board: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/251336804760

Comment: @Mina: Yes. But do check the voltage levels if both display and USB-Serial adapter are 5V compatible you are OK. If both are 3.3V compatible you are OK. Otherwise you'll need a level shifter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "directly" connect a 7-seg to the pc without some aditional logic. Also, I don't know if you notice, but the display you mentioned has a on-board microcontroller already.